# 'mouseover' and 'mouseleave' prevents 'click' mouseevent in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I have a d3 force graph that currently has a mouseover event on a node which highlights the node being "mouseover'd" and a mouseleave event which takes restores all the nodes back (so no longer highlighted). I am trying to add an action that allows the user to 'click' on a node and it will leave that node highlighted (aka yellow stroke) until they either click it again or click another node.

The issue(s) here is the mouseleave event basically resets all nodes once the mouse leaves which is undoing the click event. Also, for some reason I can't add the condition of checking the JSON for "selected" when doing the highlight function. Here is a code snippet with the JSON at the end for reference.

```
    node = node
            .data(root.nodes)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .call(force.drag)
            .on('mouseover', connectedNodes) // highlights nodes+neighbors
            .on('mouseleave', restore) // resets
            .on('click', highlight) // suppose to highlight current node;

function connectedNodes() {

        d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;

        // Changes to all but the neighboring nodes
        node.style("opacity", function (o) { return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.1; })
            .style("stroke", function (o) { return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? "black" : "black"; });

        // Changes to all but neighboring links
        link.style("opacity", function (o) { return d.index==o.source.index | d.index==o.target.index ? 1 : 0.1; })
            .style("stroke-width", function (o) { return d.index==o.source.index | d.index==o.target.index ? 2 : null; });
        // Maintains opacity of selected node.
        return d3.select(this)
                .style("opacity",1)
                .attr("r", 30);
}

function restore() {
    node.style("opacity", 1)
            .style("stroke", null);

    link.style("opacity", 1)
            .style("stroke-width", null);

function highlight() {
        return d3.select(this).style("stroke", "yellow");
}
```

Here is the function highlight() that it is suppose to look like but this doesn't work and ends up not doing anything on click.

```
function highlight() {
    if (function(d) { return d.selected } == false)
    {
        function(d) { return d.selected} = true;
        return d3.select(this).style("stroke", "yellow");
    }
    else {
        function(d) { return d.selected = false } = false;
        return d3.select(this).style("stroke", null);
    }
}
```

Here is the JSON

```
{
"nodes": [
{"fixed":true,"data": {"id": "foo","idType":"USERNAME","visible":true },"selected":false},
{"fixed":true,"data": {"id": "bar","idType":"USERNAME","visible":true },"selected": false}
],
"links": [
{classes":null,"data":{"color":"blue"","source":"foo","target":"bar","visible":true},"grabbable":false},
{classes":null,"data":{"color":"blue"","source":"bar","target":"foo","visible":true},"grabbable":false}
]}
```

Comment: What do you actually want to check in `highlight`? The code you currently have will never do anything because you're declaring functions that are never called. The `d` that's bound to the element would be an argument to `highlight`.

Comment: In highlight I am trying to check the JSON for whether it is currently highlighted (aka "selected" in the JSON). So an example is if I click on a node it checks in the JSON if it is "selected". If selected is false it changes it to true and highlights the node.

Comment: This is not what your current code does. You need to declare `d` as an argument to `highlight` and use that: `function highlight(d) { if(d.selected == false) { ... } else { ... } }`

Comment: I see! I did not realize I could pass d to highlight. I have tried that and it works! That gives me an idea on how I can to solve my mouseoff event issue. Is it possible in d3 to always check all of the nodes if selected = true of that node? Then in my highlight() I can just change it so it sets d.selected to true or false while I have something that always checks for whether something is selected and keeps it highlighted (which hopefully won't be killed by my restore() function since it will still have selected=true)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but you can simply select all elements and then use `.filter()` to filter out the ones you're not interested in, i.e. the ones that are not selected.

Comment: Apologies for being scatterbrained. I'll try to elaborate a little bit further. The issue I'm still having is the issue of maintaining the highlight() function since it clashes with my other functionality of being able to hover on a node which highlights the node and neighboring while lowering the opacity of all other nodes. Then when you move the mouse away off the node (mouseleave) it activates the restore() function. Restore is causing the cancelation of the highlight. I tried adding .filter(function (d){return d.selected==true}) to the restore function but it still didn't work. Sorry again